# Double for loop in R creating a matrix

Tags: r

I would like to create a 5x5 matrix in R using two for loops. 
I have 5 numbers p_j and q_i with i and j in {1,2,3,4,5}. 
I would like to create a matrix with where the element in (j,i) is given by p_j * q_j. j-th row and i-th column. 
So, first of all I would like to create an empty matrix `m` and then filling the matrix using the for loops.

> for (i in 1:5){   for (j in 1:5){
>          } }

Comment: Must you use the double loop? Either `p %*% t(q)`   or ``outer(p,q, `*`)``  seem like better solutions.

Comment: I am afraid, my R skills are not sufficient in order to understand your comment. Could you work out your comment as a second answer?

Comment: As an aside-- R indexes by [row, column], so you would want to assemble your matrix that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have variables named "p_1", "p_2" in the working environment:

```
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
for (i in 1:5) { 
  for (j in 1:5) { 
    mymatrix[i, j] <- get(paste("p_", j, sep="")) * 
                      get(paste("q_", i, sep=""))
  }
}
```

Comment: mymatrix[i, j] is the element in the i-th row and j-th column, right?

Comment: mymatrix[i, j] is the ith row and the jth column. I'm not sure exactly what arrangement of your numbers you want, or how your data is represented. If you have variables named "p_1", "p_2", etc, this answer will work, but that's absolutely not the best way to store your data in R. They should be 2 seperate vectors named p and q, and then you can access your numbers with p[1], p[2], etc.

Answer (score 4):

I will walk through two solutions that I proposed. Both of these solutions avoid any explicit looping. Mostly in R, if it is easy to avoid a loop,  you probably should.  First, let's get some example data.

```
set.seed(2017)
p = sample(5)
q = sample(5)
p
[1] 5 3 2 1 4
q
[1] 4 1 2 5 3
```

Here p and q are randomly generated.  The `set.seed` part is so that we both get the same "random" numbers.

**Solution 1 - matrix multiplication**

```
p %*% t(q)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20    5   10   25   15
[2,]   12    3    6   15    9
[3,]    8    2    4   10    6
[4,]    4    1    2    5    3
[5,]   16    4    8   20   12
```

`%*%` is the way to specify matrix multiplication in R.
`p %*% t(q)`  multiplies the 5x1 matrix p by the 1x5 matrix t(q),  the transpose of q, resulting in the 5x5 matrix with the desired answer.

**Solution 2 - outer**

```
outer(p,q, `*`)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20    5   10   25   15
[2,]   12    3    6   15    9
[3,]    8    2    4   10    6
[4,]    4    1    2    5    3
[5,]   16    4    8   20   12
```

The function `outer` in r, creates the "outer product" of two vectors - that is, it takes all combinations of an element of p and an element of q and combines them using the function that you supplied,  in this case `*`,   exactly the calculation that you are asking for.   Actually,  this could have been written more succinctly as `outer(p,q)`  because the default function to use to combine p & q is `*`.

Comment: P and q are not elements in the global environment: there are 10 variables, named `p_1`, `p_2`, ... `p_5`, and `q_1` ... `q_5`. Also, the question explicitly asks for a solution using two for loops. Even though it's not best practice in R, answering with a non-for-looping answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ConCave  I originally wrote this as a comment that noted it did not use loops.  The OP _asked_ me to include it as an answer.

Comment: Nevermind them, sorry about that. Thanks for providing a more detailed explanation of your comment.