# creating a matrix/dataframe with two for loops in R

Tags: r, data-structures

This is my first post on SO, so be kind!

My question is vaguely related to this one: 
[Double for loop in R creating a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376020/double-for-loop-in-r-creating-a-matrix)

I want to create a matrix/dataframe and the approach my mind has chosen is to nest two for loops, one to create the first row and the second to repeat it for the rows I nedd.

I could successfully create the first loop, but I can't seem to iterate it for the number of rows I need.

I'm sure that there is a better way to do this, anyway, this is the for loop that gives the result I need for the first row:

```
x <- character(0)
for(j in 1:18){
    x <- c(x, sum(it_mat[1, 2:26] == j))
}
```

it_mat is a matrix of 417 rows and 26 columns, where the first column is a string vector with various names and the subsequent columns are randomly generated numbers from 1 to 18.

Here's the first row:

```
[1,] "Charlie" "14" "3"  "9"  "14" "3"  "9"  "11" "11" "18"  "17"  "16"  "5"   "18"  "6"   "10"  "3"   "9"   "9"   "3"   "18"  "12"  "8"   "5"   "5"  "4"
```

I want to create a matrix/df where I count how many times, for each name, each number appearead.

The for loop I created above gives me the result I want for the first row:

```
x
[1] "0" "0" "4" "1" "3" "1" "0" "1" "4" "1" "2" "1" "0" "2" "0" "1" "1" "3"
```

I really can't iterate it for the subsequent rows with another for loop, there must be something very mundane that I do wrong.

This is my best attempt:

```
tr_mat <- matrix(, nrow = 147, ncol = 18)
for(i in 1:147){
    x <- character()
    for(j in 1:18){
        x <- c(x, sum(it_mat[i, 2:26] == j))
    }
    tr_mat <- rbind(tr_mat, x)
}
```

I went on it all afternoon and now I give up and reach out to you, before you give me the correct way to do it, please explain what I'm doing wrong in the nested for loops try, I might learn something.

I hope I explained myself, sorry if I've been too verbose.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: For those that voted to close could you post a comment stating what the OP could do to improve.  This is a first time poster and it's important we teach desired behaviors rather than discourage posting on SO at all.

Comment: Do `tr_mat[i, ] <- x`, not `tr_mat <- rbind(tr_mat, x)`. (You are rbinding a matrix of `NA`values with 147 new rows.)

Comment: Could you include a short snippet of 'it_mat'? before the loop?

Comment: @lefft Maybe you could use the input matrix in my answer.

Comment: OP has tried his best and put enough efforts before posting his question. We must encourage such new joiners!!

Comment: My suggestion to the OP  is it would be great to make the code completely reproducible. The OP provided good detailed codes and some desired outputs, but it is not clear what `it_mat` is. This is why I voted to close this post. If the OP can provided reproducible example of the `it_mat`, I will retract my vote and give this post an upvote.

Comment: good suggestion from @www !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, using base R. Note that `*apply` functions are loops in disguise.

```
tr_mat2 <- sapply(1:18, function(j) sapply(1:147, function(i) sum(it_mat[i, 2:26] == j)))
```

Note that this code will produce a matrix of numbers, while your `tr_mat` is of mode `character`:

```
all.equal(tr_mat, tr_mat2)
#[1] "Modes: character, numeric"
```

**DATA.**
This is the dataset generation code that I have used to test the code above.

```
set.seed(7966)    # make the results reproducible
it_mat <- t(replicate(147, c(sample(letters, 1), sample(18, 25, TRUE))))
```

**EDIT.**
Following the suggestion in the comments by MKR, here is the OP's code corrected with my modification in the comment to his (the OP's) post.

```
tr_mat <- matrix(, nrow = 147, ncol = 18)
for(i in 1:147){
    x <- character()
    for(j in 1:18){
        x <- c(x, sum(it_mat[i, 2:26] == j))
    }
    tr_mat[i, ] <- x
}
```

This is the code that I have used to produce the matrix `tr_mat` refered to in the `all.equal` test above.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went with your solutions as I almost resolved it the same way by myself but I didn't nested it correctly. I'm actually more familiar with the apply family than loops in R (especially tapply, great for investigating databases), but lately I've been using Python more so...

Answer (score 3):

@RuiBarradesh has pin-pointed the actual problem in OP last attempt. There is another way to fix the OP code using `rbind`.

```
# Do not create rows at this place. Let the rows be added with rbind
tr_mat <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 18)   #(, nrow = 147, ncol = 18)
for(i in 1:147){
  x <- character()
  for(j in 1:18){
    x <- c(x, sum(it_mat[i, 2:26] == j))
  }
  tr_mat <- rbind(tr_mat, x)
}

tr_mat      # This will display correct result too
```

Comment: Thank to you as well, and sorry to everybody if I didn't add a reproducible example but yesterday I was too burned to toy with sample() as well. I gave the first row of it_mat thinking it was enough. Sory about that. Anyway there was a typing mistake in nrow: it should have been 417 and not 147.

Answer (score 1):

Do you realy need 2 loops? Here is a solution without any loop using data.table and combination of melt/dcast functions:

```
library(data.table)

# dataset ----------------------------
seed(2018)

it_mat<-data.frame(c1=c('Charlie','John','Peter'))

for(i in 2:26){
  it_mat[,paste0('c',i)]<-sample(1:18,3)
}

# calculation ----------------------------

it_mat<-data.table(it_mat)
it_mat<-melt(it_mat,id.vars='c1')
it_mat[,.N,by=.(c1,value)][order(c1,value)]

dcast(it_mat[,.N,by=.(c1,value)][order(c1,value)],c1~value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not familiar with data.table. I don't like to use packages that replace base R functions because, as a newbie, I think it is more educative to learn the chops the hard way, if you understand what I mean. Thanks for your input, appreciated anyway.