# Looping through a list of dataframes to return a matrix of k-means clusters with fixed centroids in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-structures, k-means

this is my second post, and let's say it predates the first one, which I'll link here:

[creating a matrix/dataframe with two for loops in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723716/creating-a-matrix-dataframe-with-two-for-loops-in-r/48724195#48724195)

I won't repeat the newbie mistake I made there so here you go with a copy of the data:

```
 > dput(head(dfn,1))
structure(c(-0.936707666207839, 0.684585833497428, -1.15671769161442, 
-0.325882814790034, 0.334512025995239, 0.335054315282587, 0.0671142954097706, 
-0.544867778136127, -0.958378799317135, 1.26734044843021, -0.483611966400142, 
-0.0781514731365092, -0.671994127070641, 0.332218249471269, 0.942550991112822, 
0.15534532610427, 0.192944412985922, 0.206169118270958, 0.424191119850985, 
-0.193936625653784, -0.574273356856365, -0.176553706556564, 0.696013509222779, 
0.118827262744793, 0.0649996884597108, 0.470171960447926, -0.570575475596488, 
0.336490371668436, 0.475005575251838, 0.010357165551236, 0.284525279467858, 
0.523668394513643, -0.0290958105736766, 0.62018540798656, 1.37452329937098, 
0.456726128895017), .Dim = c(1L, 36L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("2015-01-30", "2015-02-27", "2015-03-31", "2015-04-30", 
    "2015-05-29", "2015-06-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-30", 
    "2015-10-30", "2015-11-30", "2015-12-31", "2016-01-29", "2016-02-29", 
    "2016-03-31", "2016-04-29", "2016-05-31", "2016-06-30", "2016-07-29", 
    "2016-08-31", "2016-09-30", "2016-10-31", "2016-11-30", "2016-12-30", 
    "2017-01-31", "2017-02-28", "2017-03-31", "2017-04-28", "2017-05-31", 
    "2017-06-30", "2017-07-31", "2017-08-31", "2017-09-29", "2017-10-31", 
    "2017-11-30", "2017-12-29")))
```

It is a time series database of 417 rows with 36 time frames (each month for the last 3 years).

Here's the code I used to create a list of dataframes:

```
ProgrSubset <- function(x,i) { x[,i:sum(i,11)] }
dfList <- lapply(1:25, function(x) ProgrSubset(dfn, x) )
```

dfList is then a list of 25 dataframes, subsetted from the original one by a rolling window of 12 months.

Now I want to run a k-means algorithm on each dataframe of the list and store the clusters numbers for each iteration in a matrix called it_mat.

But here's the grief, I want the centroids to be the ones of the previous run (if they are fixed from the first run would be great anyway).

I have no problem doing it "by hand":

```
it_mat <- cbind(ref_data$sec_id)
k = 18
cl <- kmeans(dfList[[1]], centers = k, nstart = 10)
it_mat <- cbind(it_mat, cl$cluster)
head(it_mat) #first iteration

colnames(cl$centers) <- colnames(dfn[,2:13])
k <- cl$centers
cl <- kmeans(dfList[[2]], centers = k, nstart = 10)
it_mat <- cbind(it_mat, cl$cluster)
head(it_mat) #second iteration
```

It should be then be straightforward to loop it through the list of databases but it is a no show: the for loop I devised only return a matrix with just the first iteration:

```
it_mat <- cbind(ref_data$sec_id)
for(i in 1:25){
    if(i == 1){
        k = 18
        cl <- kmeans(dfList[[i]], centers = k, nstart = 10)
        it_mat <- cbind(it_mat, cl$cluster)
    }else{
        colnames(cl$centers) <- colnames(dfn[,i:i+11])
        k = cl$centers
        cl <- kmeans(dfList[[i]], centers = k, nstart = 10)
        it_mat <- cbind(it_mat, cl$cluster)
    }
}
```

Maybe it stops after the error: `Error: empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers` ?

But I don't care if a cluster is empty.

I've also tried to loop just the subsequent iterations after the first one, to make it simpler without the `if` and the `else`:

```
for(i in 2:25){
    colnames(cl$centers) <- colnames(dfn[,2:13])
    k <- cl$centers
    cl <- kmeans(dfList[[i]], centers = k, nstart = 10)
    it_mat <- cbind(it_mat, cl$cluster)
}
```

Still the same result: a matrix with just the first iteration.

I've also tried to use `it_mat[ ,i] <- cl$cluster`instead of `it_mat <- cbind(it_mat, cl$cluster)` but it's the same.

I'll appreciate any kind of help, comment or suggestion: I'm probably making some very stupid mistake like in my previous question or I choose a very difficult path complicating my job.

My main goal is to understand how clusters composition variates in certain time series.

Thanks for you time everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method, though I cannot get it to work with your small dataset and `k`. Perhaps it'll work better with your actual data. If you don't want to know why/how this works, skip to **TL;DR**.

### Use of `Reduce`

The trick I'm using is `Reduce`, whose first argument is a function with two arguments. A trivial demonstration of it is:

```
Reduce(function(a,b) 2*a+b, 1:4)
```

This is equivalent to `2*1+2`, then `2*(2*1+2)+3`, etc. Perhaps uninspiring in its current form. Let's put in some printing, and "accumulate" the data:

```
Reduce(function(a,b) {
  cat(paste(c(a,b), collapse=","), "\n")
  return(2*a+b)
}, 1:4, accumulate=TRUE)
# 1,2 
# 4,3 
# 11,4 
# [1]  1  4 11 26
```

So, the first call of the function takes the first element of the vector `1` and the second element `2` and calls the function. Then it takes that returned value (`2*1+2` is `4`) and the third element of the vector `3` and does its magic. And so on.

One "assumption" typically made when dealing with `Reduce` is that the two values must be the same "type" of object. This does not need to be, so I'll trick things a little.

Another thing to note is that it is starting on the first two elements of the list, which is also not a strict requirement. If we set `init`, we can control what `a` is on the first call.

```
Reduce(function(a,b) {
  cat(paste(c(a,b), collapse=","), "\n")
  return(2*a+b)
}, 1:4, init=99, accumulate=TRUE)
# 99,1 
# 199,2 
# 400,3 
# 803,4 
# [1]   99  199  400  803 1610
```

Notice how each element in the list was used in only one function call?

### Adding `kmeans`

So my technique is to think about what we want on the `n`th call of the function: we want the previous cluster object from `n-1` and the `n`th data. Realize that *"previous cluster object"* looks a lot like the 199, 400, and 803 from that last example. We'll write a function that assumes the previous cluster object is the first argument, and the data is the second.

```
my_cascade_kmeans <- function(prevclust, dat) {
  kmeans(dat, centers = prevclust$centers, nstart = 10)
}
Reduce(my_cascade_kmeans, dfList, accumulate = TRUE)
```

(BTW: I'm collecting the entire cluster output instead of just the centers, since ultimately we want to end up with a list of cluster objects.)

The problem, as you'll quickly find out (and recall), is that the first time this is called, it is called with the first two elements. So instead, we want to declare the initial value. Two ways to handle that:

1. `Reduce(my_cascade_kmeans, dfList, init=list(centers=5), accumulate=TRUE)`

   This is using the convenience that both the cluster object from `kmeans` and a static `list(centers=5)` can be indexed with `$centers`, and they return what I think we need.
2. `Reduce(my_cascade_kmeans, dfList, init=NULL, accumulate=TRUE)`

   For this to work, we'd need to modify our function to expect `NULL` in `prevclust` and deal with it accordingly. There are times when this may be better.

I prefer option 1, because it places the "default `k` value" in the original `Reduce` call and not necessarily buried in the function code. But you may prefer it there, over to you.

For this answer, I'm reducing the initial clusters from 18 to 4 ... anything higher and it fails with `Error: empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers`, which I'm guessing is due to a truncated sample dataset.

### TL;DR

```
my_cascade_kmeans <- function(prevclust, dat) {
  kmeans(dat, centers = prevclust$centers, nstart = 10)
}
clusters <- Reduce(my_cascade_kmeans, dfList, init = list(centers=4), accumulate = TRUE)

length(clusters)
# [1] 26
```

You might balk at this, but this is what we told it to do: *"initialize the vector by prepending `list(centers=4)` to the beginning, and then accumulate the results"*, so we should not be surprised that it is one-longer than what we started with.

```
clusters[[1]]
# $centers
# [1] 4
```

That confirms it. Clean it up with

```
clusters <- clusters[-1]
```

Now each of `clusters` is the return from `kmeans(...)` using the previous

```
clusters[[1]]
# K-means clustering with 4 clusters of sizes 2, 4, 3, 3
# Cluster means:
#         [,1]
# 1  0.9759631
# 2  0.1646323
# 3 -0.4514542
# 4 -1.0172681
# Clustering vector:
# 2015-01-30 2015-02-27 2015-03-31 2015-04-30 2015-05-29 2015-06-30 2015-07-31 2015-08-31 2015-09-30 2015-10-30 2015-11-30 
#          4          1          4          3          2          2          2          3          4          1          3 
# 2015-12-31 
#          2 
# Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
# [1] 0.16980147 0.12635651 0.02552839 0.02940412
#  (between_SS / total_SS =  94.0 %)
# Available components:
# [1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"        
# [9] "ifault"
```

Icing on the cake, this works as well with 2 or 2000 datasets.

Comment: wow, your solution is really of a high level expertise, it's gonna take some time for me to understand it and implement it, but congrats for now and thank you very much!

Comment: I agree that `Reduce` is a what I'll term a "higher-level language construct"; not that it reflects any intelligence on the programmer, more so a different way of looking at "iterating through data", frequent among higher-level languages. I think "playing with it" was the best way I got used to using it, and though I don't use it often, whenever I do use it, the solution seems way more flexible and elegant (a hang-up of mine).